# How to analyze a dynamical system when $t\to\infty?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Let $B$ be number of bees per acre, measured in hundreds of bees, while $C$ is the weight of trees per acre, in thousands of pounds. Suppose that the time is measured in months. $$\frac{dB}{dt}=.1(1-.01B+.005C)B$$ $$\frac{dC}{dt}=.03(1+.04B-.1C)C$$ 
Suppose one acre of land has 10,000 pounds of trees in it, and a beehive of 2,000 bees is introduced...(1)

> What happens to the populations in future time?

---

What I've done:

I found all the equilibrium points and I analyze each of them.

$1. (0,0), 2.(0,1/.1), 3.(1/.01,0), 4.(525/4,125/2)$

1. and 4. are source points and the rest of them are saddle points.

I also draw the phase portrait, but I don't know how to relate the information given in (1).

As you can see none of the equilibrium points are stable so I can't use this $lim_{t\to\infty}B(t)=\overline x$.

Can someone help me to answer the question please?

I greatly appreciate any assistance you may provide.

Comment: the easiest way to answer this is just run a solver, since you have the initial conditions.

Comment: @SZN What is run a solver? Do you mean to solve analytically the system of DE?

Comment: No. I mean look up how to solve such equations numerically. If you have matlab, ODE45 provides a very competitive package of systems of ODEs.

Comment: @SZN No, I can't use software. What if this question appears in my exam? I not able to use the computer in exams.

Comment: If you must solve this at an exam, you might want to check much more carefully the type of the fixed point in the positive quadrant.

Comment: @SZN Good news, no solver is needed here.

Comment: @Did yes. I had a typo with the 4. point, it is a source.

Comment: No. Look again.

Comment: @Did I don't see it, the phase portrait also shows what I said about the type of the points.

Comment: Maybe you can write the Jacobian and what you got as the eigenvalues at each of those critical points. For example, I get two negative eigenvalues for your fourth critical point, which is not a source.

Comment: @Moo you're right, how could I not see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Around the nontrivial fixed point:

[image: Around the nontrivial fixed point]

Comment: A sink point then.

Comment: So when $t\to\infty$ all the solutions in the positive quadrant  goes to 4. this means that population of bees will grow faster than trees and both are going to live 'forever'? i.e they don't go to $(0,0)$ so they are not going to die.

Comment: Or when $t\to\infty$, the maximum size of both population is 4.?